# How do you pass query string parameters to the AWS API Gateway client with the Javascript SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an endpoint defined in AWS API Gateway that uses a Lambda integration. The Lambda function expects query string parameters that would be available in the `event` object passed to it.

My API is at `example.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/my-resource` and I have query string parameters like `foo=test`.

So the full endpoint would be

`example.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/my-resource?foo=test`

**I can visit this endpoint in a browser** or request it in postman, and get the expected response, so I know that the API Gateway is configured properly. However when I use the Javascript SDK, I can't seem to pass query string parameters.

According to the last part of [this page from the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-javascript.html), I should be able to just pass in a JSON object that will be interpreted as query string parameters, like so:

```
var apiClient = apigClientFactory.newClient();
var requestParams = {"foo": "test"};
apiClient.myResourceGet(requestParams).then(function(result) {
    // Do something with the response
});
```

However, in my case `requestParams` seems to be ignored. In the Lambda function, the `event` has an empty `queryStringParameters` field. **How can I pass the key/values defined in the `requestParams` object as query string parameters to this endpoint?**